# Get "real" Datarow after adding element to DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

### Solved:

I have solved it by subscribing to `row.Loaded` - once this method gets called, I can traverse the visual tree and find the `DataGridCellsPresenter` which I need to manipulate.

Which of course makes sense, should invest into understanding WPF more :(

### Original question:

I need to manipulate the `DataGridCellsPresenter` when a row has been added into a Datagrid. I tried hooking into the `LoadingRow` event and access it via `e.Row`, however the row has not been inserted into the datagrid when the event occurs (so there's no `DataGridCellsPresenter` in `e.Row`s visual tree and `e.Row` isn't in the DataGrids rows yet).

As far as I'm aware, there doesn't seem to be a `LoadedRow` event. Is there any way I can access the newly added row when it has been loaded?

PS. I tried updating the layout on both the datagrid and `e.Row`, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve the row from it's index:

```
    //found this on SO, I don't remember who, credit to original coder
    public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
            grid.UpdateLayout();
            grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }
```

Or by it's data item:

```
var row= DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(youritem);
```

EDIT
This method might help you too:

```
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
                            where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            // If the child is not of the request child type child
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // child element found.
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundChild;
    }
```

Comment: The row seems to be the same as ``e.Row``, you have however sparked an idea for me, will post it in my post. Thanks!